# Trying to parse request body in Grape API

Tags: rack, ruby-grape, grape-api

So I have an API where one of the entry points looks something like:

```
module SomeModule
  module SomeOtherModule
    class Users < SomeModule::SomeOtherModule::Base
      helpers do
        params :user do
          requires :user, type: Hash do
            requires :device_id, type: String, desc: "Device ID"
          end
        end
      end

      desc "Some description"
      params do
        use :user
      end

      put "/", route_name: :v1_put_user_path do
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**SomeModule::SomeOtherModule::Base** inherits from **Grape::API**

My client is sending the params in the body - which look like:

```
{"user[device_id]":"xyz"}
```

Since this come like a string the I fail to recognise them.Therefore return:

```
{"error":"user is missing"}
```

This means that on my server I'm getting:

```
{"user[device_id]"=>"00999877",
  "route_info"=>
   ...
```

When I'm expecting to see:

```
{"user"=>{"device_id"=>"00999877"},
  "route_info"=>
  ...
```

Any ideas on how should I define my params?...or maybe someone has stumble upon this issue and can provide some solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your params block like this:

```
module SomeModule
    module SomeOtherModule
        class Users < SomeModule::SomeOtherModule::Base
            params do
                group :user, type: Hash do
                    requires :device_id, type: String, desc: "Device ID"
                end
            end
            put "/", route_name: :v1_put_user_path do
                ...
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**

Explaining the solution...

If your client is sending a JSON like the code below, then you have to define a group block and define the type parameter as Hash. The same rule applies when your client sends a "form-field" like user[device_id].

```
{ user: { device_id: 1 } }
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've just noticed that your client is sending an incorrect JSON to your service. This JSON shouldn't be...

```
{"user[device_id]":"xyz"}
```

...because it's not what your API is expecting. Instead, it should send

```
{ user: { device_id: "xyz" } }.
```

Comment: 1. My bad!. When I posted the question I should had mentioned I have the params defined within a helpers block 
2. I had a missing end
3. The user param was defined as a Hash though ;).
4. Notice that in my description I wrote that I have this issue when values are sent within the body as JSON. I have no problem when they are passed as parameters

Comment: In this case, I think that your client is sending an incorrect JSON. This JSON shouldn't be {"user[device_id]":"xyz"} because it's not what your API is expecting. Instead, he must send { user: { device_id: "xyz" } }.

Comment: I just run some tests and seems like the JSON format I expect to get is not the one I'm actually getting.Meaning I want to get: 
{
    "user": {
        "device_id": 1231232
    }
}
But the client is generating {"user[device_id]": "1"}. Which yeah, makes the point of your 'update' section

Comment: lol...just wrote a comment saying your exact words. I declared it closed!.Thx man!

Comment: lol... I'll update my answer and put in it what I commented above.